# Automatically upload after user have selected a file using fileUploadControl

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

Is there any way to automatically upload the file after user have selected a file.

These are all the events provided by FileUpload Control

Databinding
Dispose
Init
Load
Prerender
Unload

Comment: you can do it by using a little Javascipt. by clicking upload button.

Comment: <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />

This is the asp tag FileUpload control has generate, it seems that this includes both the textbox and button so i don't know what event should i use.

Comment: For more control may I recommend you look at Uploadify: http://www.uploadify.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server control generates a <input type="file" ..> html control. You need a client side event, not a server event. You just have to submit the page by using JavaScript. Use the onchange Event of the asp:UploadControl.
Look here for further explanation: [auto submit file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/792971/style-input-file-and-auto-submit)

Comment: Thank you slfan, i am going to investigate on the reference you have provide :D